# Show results on my domain only, but not Google

Tags: google-custom-search

We have bought Google Custom Search account.
It works fine and generates XML result set as expected.

Can we protect our data so that it's shown only within our domain only?

Currently the data is exposed via Google Search (http://google.com) and anybody could see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Custom Search is a solution for searching public materials, accessible to everyone (e.g. a public website of a company). It uses the same infrastructure as google.com, so anything needs to be exposed first to google.com to be visible in Custom Search.

If your intention is to search e.g. your company's intranet or sensitive data, the better solution is Google Search Appliance, which works behind the firewall.